# componentDidMount is not triggered

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi Im new to React & nodeJS, i'm trying to call my nodejs api through react and my componentDidMount is not triggered at all even after rendering the page.
Can some one please give some idea on where exactly I might be missing.

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          jobs: []
        }
      },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log("mount");
        var _this = this;
        this.serverRequest = $.ajax({
        ....
          }.bind(this)
        });
      },

      componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
      },

      render: function() {
            return (
              <div><h1>Jobs</h1>
                {this.state.jobs.map(function(job) {
                  return (
                    <div key={job.id} className="job">
                        {job.name}
                        {job.address}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            )
          }
});
```

In my NodeServer.js file i'm calling in this way, Only Jobs is being displayed in my html page

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    var htmlCode = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Component));
    response.send(htmlCode);
})
```

Comment: Try initiating the server request in `componentWillMount()`. Also, set the `serverRequest` using setState: `this.setState({serverRequest: serverRequest});` Then you reference it as `this.state.serverRequest`. Let me know if that helps? The issue might be that you're simply not rerendering the component after the server request comes back. Setting state will rerender for you, so setState inside the response callback from the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: For server side render , do not call componentDidMount, since there is no DOM for server side rendering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the React component lifecycle methods to load data when you're rendering in the backend, this will only work in the client. When you render the component on the server, it is only rendered once, without the data. The data is loaded asynchronously, when it is finished, your component has already been rendered. You have to fetch your data outside the component, then pass it to the component as a prop.